# There should be an article (A or The)

Tags: american-english, adverbs, british-english, zero-article

I was reading a novel and I think, there is a mistake, they missed an article as per me but I am not sure yet, so putting this here.

**In the book, it has been written:**

> Destiny, it is way over the horizon.

**As per me, it should be:**

> Destiny, it is **a/the** way over the horizon.

My point is that, way is a countable noun and singular as well so an article should be there.

Comment: Read this *way* as *far*.

Comment: *As per me*? - *In my opinion.*

Comment: Nope. In this context, _way_ is not even a noun. Methinks your theory was _way_ off.

Answer (score 10):

It is not a mistake. In this usage, *way* is an adverb rather than a noun. The adverb *way* means "far", "at a great distance", etc.

Comment: I wonder - if the phrase were structured with a full verb instead of BE, say, "Destiny... it *hovers* way over the horison", would that be grammatical.

Comment: @CopperKettle Yes.

Comment: In English, the be verb is pretty much a real verb, unlike in some languages, like Japanese.

Comment: I think it's way too simplistic and misleading to baldly say way means "far", "at a great distance". Those are reasonable paraphrasings *in the specific context of "over the horizon"*, but more generally it would be better to say it's an ***intensifier*** with the sense of *very [much], excessively, a great deal*. Sure, it's a "distance-based" figurative usage, but those origins are pretty distant in common usages today such as *"He's way smarter than me"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "She's far smarter than me." is just fine. But there is certainly a difference between the two cases as "She is much smarter than me" is okay but "it is much over the horizon" is not.

Comment: @Mark: I think that's just hair-splitting over the fact that certain *combinations* don't sound "idiomatic". In OP's context we can directly replace *over the horizon* with *distant*, for example. But whereas native speakers would be quite happy with *very distant*, they mostly wouldn't like *far distant* any more than *much distant* (though I imagine increasing numbers would now be okay with *way distant*). But I think these are just issues of idiomatic currency, not grammar or meaning. My point is that *way* today means more than just *at a great distance*; it shouldn't be thus "defined".

Comment: @FumbleFingers As an aside, I'm not sure I agree that idiomatic currency can be so easily separated from grammar/meeting. But yes, I agree with you that this idiomatic meaning is important.

Comment: @Mark: All (or *nearly* all) language use is metaphoric. By the time it gets to words like *currency* we barely register even the flowing current, let alone the underlying *to run*. And that's just *nouns and verbs*, which are relatively stable since they reference identifiable things and actions. Prepositions, adverbs, and the like slip and slide around all the time, since all they do most of the time is glue the important words together.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. Sorry If I misspoke.

Comment: @Panzercrisis, I know, just was a little off-kilter from reading a textbook page on auxiliary verb characteristics, one of them being their ability to precede some kinds of adverbs which full verbs cannot precede (*often, never* - frequency adverbs \ *naturally, definitely, fortunately* - commentative adverbs, or 'disjuncts' is the author's parlance).

Answer (score 3):

You read it this way -

> Destiny, it's [way] over the horizon.

Though informal, *way-over* something means *at a considerable distance/degree.*

Read the 40th point [here](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/way%20over%20there).

Comment: I think *way over* usually has no dash inside.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I think, Publisher should have put it in a right way. it should be "way-over" in the book.

Comment: @user62015 DamkerngT. is right; *way-over* is not an English expression, and does not conform to any standard template for constructing expressions.

Comment: I disagree with the way you've "deconstructed" the elements. It should be **Destiny, it's [way] over the horizon.** The actual word *way* really just functions as an [optional] intensifier, as in *"Does my bum look [way] too big in this?"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers corrected. I just wanted to describe that way over means intense or more in degree or distance.

Comment: @Maulik: Downvote duly reversed. That's a good link, btw. I notice the *41st point* offers ***considerably*** as a synonym/definition, which you've deftly alluded to in your text. I don't understand your hyphenated *way-over* or user62015's comment thereto though - I can't imagine even a hopelessly-contrived context where that hyphen would be credible.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is poorly phrased.  It should be more like:

> Destiny...  It is way over the horizon.

The use/abuse of the comma is confusing, and kind of inexcusable in this case.

[edit] Also, as others have said, "way over" as a measure of distance makes a lot more sense than trying to use "way" as a verb.

Comment: I agree - but this doesn't address OP's question.

Comment: What book is the quote from? I'd be very careful about dubbing something "poorly phrased" until I knew more about its full context. I'll bet some mighty good authors penned some "poorly phrased" stuff – particularly if we only look at a 7-word excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you shouldn't have an article here.  The sentence:

> Destiny, it is **way** over the horizon.

means the same thing as:

> Destiny, it is **far** over the horizon.

But saying:

> Destiny, it is **a/the way** over the horizon.

means that destiny is a/the means to find your way over the horizon.  That's probably not what the book meant.  What they probably meant was that destiny is very far away, even being past the horizon.  Hence they could easily just say:

> Detinity, it is far over the horizon.

Here, whether you use the word "way" or the word "far", it means the same thing, and neither word acts as a noun in this case.